# How to get params value from POST request in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlcomponents

First I fire post request When user submit that form debugger area in inspect element shows the value of params. But How I will get that value in native ios `Swift` ?

Can any one have idea ?

Some what I know `NSURLComponents` used but I am confused how implement ?

Here I share images.

**POST paramater seen Method**

[image: POST paramater seen Method0]

**Params field**

[image: Params field]

What I require is how to get sid in native ios SDK swift.

I fired request using post method then I will get sid from param .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). This library makes it really easy to implement post requests in Swift. In your case this could somehow look like the following code:

```
let parameters:Parameters = [
       "sid": 1000
]

Alamofire.request("https://yoururl", parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
   print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
   print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
}
```

Comment: I do not want to pass any parameter. But I want it from url response